# Firebase Pubsub Schedule Job can't run result is: "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to realise a leaderboard for my App which should rewrite every 24h, but I can't get it to work... The job doesn't even start.

This is all I found about the function, but it doesn't help me.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

And this is my function:

```
exports.leaderboardjob = functions.region('europe-west1').pubsub.schedule( '0 0 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    await leaderboard();
    console.log("job done");
    return null;
});

async function leaderboard(){

    const rdb = admin.firestore();

    const ref = rdb.ref('users');

    try {
        await ref.orderByChild('xp').limitToLast(2).on('child_added', (snapshot) => { //test first with 2 results
            console.log(snapshot.key);
        });

    } catch (error) {
         console.log('error: ' + error.message);
    }

    return{
        result: ok
    }
}
```

I already moved the function to my region europe-west1 like all my other functions.

error that I get back when I call this function (leaderboardjob) manually:

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName":"projects/censored/locations/europe-west1/jobs/firebase-schedule-leaderboardjob-europe-west1", "pubsubTopic":"projects/censored/topics/firebase-schedule-leaderboardjob-europe-west1", "status":"UNAUTHENTICATED", "targetType":"PUB_SUB"}
```

Maybe its just not possible, if not: can someone explain me how to realise something like this with functions?

EDIT: I forgot to tell, that I gave the function the role with a new account "pubsub.subscriber"

Comment: I found this related blog on how to [schedule Cloud Functions for Firebase (cron)](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html), it also provided a [sample in GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/delete-unused-accounts-cron/functions/index.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just deleted the whole function and tested it with a new name.

I don't know why, but this worked...

You don't even need to add a role. Everything works just fine.